# Is it possible to determine the byte order of the system without programming on Windows?

Tags: windows, hardware-detection, endian

I would like to know how the underlying hardware system arranges the bytes in memory (whether in big or little endian). Is it possible to figure this out on Windows without programming (as suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181951/how-to-check-whether-a-system-is-big-endian-or-little-endian)?

I read that the byte order depends on the processor. Out of curiosity I would like to know what kind of byte order my processor needs without writing, compiling, linking and executing a C/C++ program. The background to the question is simply that I would like to learn more about the possibilities of my operating system.

Comment: The only way without program I can think of would be to read the include files provided by the compiler or C library. You will probably symbols that name the byte order. The byte order is relevant for programming, at least if you write non-portable programs, but not for using programs. Please [edit] your question and explain why you have the requirement to find out the byte order *without programming*.

Comment: @Bodo I agree with you. The background to the question is simply that I would like to learn more about the possibilities of my operating system.

Comment: If you want to know the byte order without programming you could ask your favorite search engine. x68 compatible processors use little endian. Often it depends on the processor, but there are processors that support both little endian and big endian. In the latter case the choice is left to the OS and/or development tools.

Comment: @Bodo there are even ARM System on Module chips which have several different parts bolted together and are randomly big and little endian, and also swap MSB and LSB within bytes, so when reading from one device in the chip you have to swap bytes and then bit swap to achieve anything sensible. They're just random kludges of electronics bolted together haphazardly and they are not much fun. Welcome to the future.

Comment: "*Is it possible to figure this out on Windows ...*" -- By asking the question with this restriction on the OS, isn't the endian always going to be little endian?  IOW is there any CPU that can (natively) run Windows that is anything but little endian?